Hom functor and Cohen-Macaulay modules
Let $A$ be a local Gorenstein $\mathbb{C}$-algebra (not necessarily regular). Let $M,N$ be maximal Cohen-Macaulay $A$-modules. Is Hom(M,N) a maximal Cohen-Macaulay A-module?
Note that I had asked this question on stackexchange, but did not get an answer.
EDIT Following the comment of Jason Starr, I wanted to add an extra assumption on $A$. We assume that $A$ is an integral domain and integrally closed i.e., $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is normal and integral. Note that, if $A$ is of Krull dimensional one, then the answer to the question is correct as Hom of torsion-free sheaves is torsion-free. Moreover, if $A$ is of Krull dimension $2$, one can observe that Hom(M,N) is reflexive, which means that in this case the question has a positive answer as well.
If the question still has a negative answer in higher dimension, I wanted to ask, is Hom(M,M) maximal Cohen-Macaulay, if $M$ is MCM?

No, that is not true.  Let $A$ be $\mathbb{C}[[s,t]/\langle st \rangle$, let $M$ be $A/\langle s \rangle$, and let $N$ be $A/\langle t \rangle$.  Then $\text{Hom}_A(M,N)$ is the zero module.

The zero module is MCM, right?

@JasonStarr Thank you for the counterexample, I have made an edit to the question.

@PiotrAchinger The zero module is CM (trivially) but not MCM because it has no support.

Then it seems like an imprecision in the literature (e.g. in Yoshino's book, Def 1.1 vs Proposition 1.2). If we define $M$ to be MCM if ${\rm depth}(M) = {\rm dim}(R)$ then the zero module is not MCM. But if we characterize it in terms of vanishing of some Ext or local cohomology, then clearly the zero module is MCM. So which is it? I think the zero module should be MCM. Terminological issues aside it would be more interesting to see an example with ${\rm Hom}(M, N)$ non-MCM and nonzero.

@PiotrAchinger You make a very good point. But, the MCM criterion also asks for the non-vanishing of the Ext or local cohomology when the degree is equal to the dimension. For example, for a MCM module of dimension n, $H^n_x$ should be non-zero. This fails in the case of zero modules. You are right that the way it is written in Proposition 1.2 of Yoshino, zero module is MCM. I think one needs to add the non-vanishing in the highest degree. You can see Theorem 1.2.8 of Bruns and Herzog to see the importance of the non-vanishing in the higherst degree.

Just to add some support to @PiotrAchinger, I think the zero module should certainly count as MCM. If you have theorems like "the kernel of a map between MCM modules is MCM, unless it's zero" or "the MCM modules, together with the zero module, form an additive category", then you should probably be wondering whether your definition of an MCM module is quite right. But people whose judgement I respect seem to disagree, so maybe I'm missing the killer argument?

Let $R$ be a local CM ring and $M,N$ be MCM modules. Then, $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N)$ has Serre property $S_2$ and that is the best you can have in general. The proof that this has $S_2$ is straightforward and anyway the question is about an example, so let me describe an example.
If $R$ is regular, then all MCM modules are free and then $\operatorname{Hom}(M,N)$ is free. So, let me further assume that $R$ is not regular. Also it has dimension at least three. Then the residue field has infinite projective dimension and so a high enough syzygy would be MCM and not free. Call this $M$. Notice that $M$ localized at any non-maximal prime is free. Take a free module $F$ mapping onto $M$ and let $N$ be the kernel. Then $N$ is also MCM and the exact sequence
$$0\to N\to F\to M\to 0$$
does not split, since $M$ is not free. So, $E=\operatorname{Ext}^1(M,N)\neq 0$ and since $M$ is free outside the maximal ideal, $E$ has finite length.
Let $x$ be an element in the maximal ideal which is a non-zero divisor in $N$. Replacing $x$ by a power if necessary, we may further assume $xE=0$. Now consider the exact sequence,
$$0\to N\to N\to N/xN\to 0$$
got by multiplication by $x$. Applying $\operatorname{Hom}(M,*)$, we get,
$$0\to \operatorname{Hom}(M,N)\to\operatorname{Hom}(M,N)\to \operatorname{Hom}(M,N/xN)\to E\to E.$$
Since the map $E\to E$ is multiplication by $x$, it is zero and so so we have a surjection
$$\operatorname{Hom}(M,N/xN)\to E$$ and the kernel is precisely
$$K=\operatorname{Hom}(M,N)/x\operatorname{Hom}(M,N)$$
Since $E$ is non-zero and finite length, we see that $K$ has depth one. So, $\operatorname{Hom}(M,N)$ has depth two.

Thank you for the fantastic counterexample!
